# Cannot read property 'getHostNode' of null occurs when I refresh on nested route

Tags: mongodb, reactjs, react-router

I am having two errors when I try to access the elements of a returned object.

```
errors are : Cannot read property '_id' of undefined 
Cannot read property 'getHostNode' of null
```

This is first part of the code where I extract data from mongoDB into ContactView Component

```
componentDidMount(){
    let contactList = 'http://localhost:5000/v1/contacts';
    let callHistory = 'http://localhost:5000/v1/call-history';
    axios.all([
        axios.get(contactList),
        axios.get(callHistory)
    ])
        .then( axios.spread((list, history) => {
            console.log(list.data);
            console.log(history.data);
            this.setState({contactList: list.data, callHistory: history.data});
        }))
        .catch(function (error) {
             console.error(error);
             });
        }


 render() {
    return (
            <BrowserRouter>
                <Switch>
                    <Route exact path="/contact/:id" component={(props)=> <ContactView contactList={this.state.contactList} id={props.match.params.id} />} />
                </Switch>
            </BrowserRouter>
    );
  }
```

In the ContactView component, I have

```
 contactId(){
        const contactList = this.props.contactList;
        const contact = _.find(contactList, contact => {return contact._id === contact._id});
        this.setState({contact: contact});
        console.log(this.state.contact) //works well at all times
        console.log(this.state.contact._id) //works initially but returns an error when I refresh on the contact/:id route
    }
```

when I console.log(this.state.contact) I get the object returned to me properly without errors

```
{_id: "5a232cea94aff40b907fc69b", name: "Dustin Briggs", phone_number: "+185738960158", address: "10 Satin road, Milky-Way 85701, USA"}
```

but when I try to access the elements in the object or do something like this console.log(this.state.contact._id) I don't get an error navigating from the root to the page but when I refresh on the page an error occurs;

I get both errors

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '_id' of undefined 
Uncaught (promise) Cannot read property 'getHostNode' of null
```

Please I need help to know what I'm doing wrong to fix this bug, which only occurs when I refresh on the `contact/:id` route

Answer (score 1):

"I don't get an error navigating from the root to the page but when I refresh on the page an error occurs;"
This is happening because when you are in root, on componentDidMount you got the data and then you are going to the page with data. But when you are directly going to the page, page is trying to access the data while it is still being fetched. So this intermediate state is causing error.

To avoid these error you can sanitize your data. As in before extracting data check if the key even defined or not. For example.

```
const contactList = this.props.contactList || [];    
const contact = _.find(contactList, contact => {
    return contact && contact._id === contact._id
});
```

Comment: Thanks, @Nidhi Agarwal any ideas how I would be able to fix the inconsistency in the state?

Comment: Have edited my answer to show how you can handle these states.

Comment: Thanks, @Nidhi-Agarwal your solution helped me to Identify where the problem is from which is from the `ContactView component`. Although I couldn't fix it directly I decided to make the id of each object the routes unique id `contact/:id`, then I extracted it by passing `id={props.match.params.id}` to the `ContactView` route which I could access and use in the `ContactView` component. I do appreciate the effort.